# change yy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yy

Tags: sql, date

I've got a bunch of records containing dates in my database that have been entered as dd/mm/yy. This was interpreted by the program I'm using (Sequel Pro) as yyyy/mm/dd.

For example, if I entered a record for August 18th 2013 as: 18-08-13, the record will instead come back as 2018-08-13.

I have many records. Is there a way to change these to either format so that they show the correct date?

Comment: Presumably the RDBMS is MySQL? Why can't you enter the date in as '2013-08-18'?

Comment: Looks like you used a string data type. You should use `date` in your DB.

Comment: What's the column's type?

Comment: Golden Rule: Never give a program or database an opportunity to interpret your date input. Remember Y2K? Entering the date in YYYY-MM-DD is the ANSI/ISO standard date format.

Comment: The columns type is date but I entered the data into it as strings. I'm not going to have to go through and manually change everything right?